# Como chamar API do youtube com vários parâmetros?

Tags: java, android, api, youtube-api

Estou tentando pegar os dados de vários videos, porém a API do Youtube é separada para videos e *playlist*, então eu usei a API de *playlist* para obter os `VideoID` de cada vídeo que esta em determinada *playlist*, porém para chamar a API de videos eu quero chamar vários videos de uma vez para evitar fazer varias chamadas na API desnecessárias assim:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id=VIDEOID1,VIDEOID2,VIDEOID3...&key={API_KEY}
```

Como passar esses `videoid` separados por virgula usando Retrofit? Andei pesquisando e li sobre mapa de *strings*, porém não parece ser oque preciso.

Atualmente estou usando o própio `Adapter` do `RecyclerView` passando a posição dentro do `onBindViewHolder` porém isso além de varias requisições desnecessárias, me trás problemas como os items da lista carregando durando o `scroll`, fica muito ruim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio você pode criar uma lista de videos, para depois concatenar criando uma `StringBuilder`. Veja

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList <String> ();
list.add("video_codigo_1");
list.add("video_codigo_2");
list.add("video_codigo_3");
list.add("video_codigo_4");

StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    if (i < (list.size() - 1))
        strB.append(list.get(i)).append(",");
    else strB.append(list.get(i));
}
String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id="
   + strB.toString() + "&key={API_KEY}";
```

Veja funcionando [no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/gcE2bE).

Uma adaptação para o Retrofit,

```
class SuaActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String BASEPATH = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/";

    private interface API {
        @GET("/videos")
        void getVideos(@QueryMap Map <String, String> 
            params, new Callback <String> callback);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        RestAdapter rest = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BASEPATH).build();
        API service = rest.create(API.class);

        List < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
        list.add("video_codigo_1");
        list.add("video_codigo_2");
        list.add("video_codigo_3");
        list.add("video_codigo_4");

        // concatena as strings separando por virgula
        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            if (i < (list.size() - 1))
            strB.append(list.get(i)).append(",");
            else strB.append(list.get(i));
        }

        Map <String, String> params = new HashMap <String, String> ();
        params.put("part", "snippet,statistics");
        params.put("id", strB.toString());
        // aqui podes colocar outros parâmetros

        service.getVideos(params, new Callback <String> () {
            // aqui você faz o tratamento para listar os videos
        });
    }
}
```

Se houver mais alguma duvida em relação aos parâmetros da Youtube API, pode conferir [na documentação](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Comment: funcionou valeu, não tinha sabia usar o string builder